# SSL with main domain name not working but subdomains do

Tags: apache, ssl, dns

So i cannot get my web server with SSL to work properly. I've googled for 4 hours now trying to get it to work, but i've had no luck.

Let's say my domain name is example.com.

I have a main site at https://example.com and then i have 4 subdomains 1.example, 2.example,3.example and 4.example.

Now the thing is, i can access all subdomains just fine, but when i try to access the main domain it says it cannot connect to the site. What am i doing wrong ??.

Using apache 2.4.20 Stable on Ubuntu 16.04.

Here is the configuration im using for the virtualhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
<Directory /var/www/example.com>
    Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>


ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

RedirectMatch 404 \.token$

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/key

ServerName www.example.com
```

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

DocumentRoot /var/www/1.example.com
<Directory /var/www/1.example.com>
    Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>


ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

RedirectMatch 404 \.token$

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/key

ServerName www.1.example.com
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

> ... but when i try to access the main domain it says it cannot connect to the site.

Since there is a web server running on the subdomains but it says that it cannot connect to the main site my guess is that your main site has a different IP address than your subdomains. In this case it does not matter how the config of the web server looks like because it will look for the web server at a different IP address and not find one.

To check the IP address for a host from your client (and only this matters) you can use tools like dig or nslookup on UNIX and Mac or or nslookup on Windows. If you see that your subdomain resolve to a different IP address than your main domain you have found the cause of your problem.

Comment: That is not the case, i run eveything from a single VPS, everything also works when i turn off SSL.